# Fastlane: How to load .env file from parent directory according to --env

Tags: ios, fastlane

1. I know that Fastlane automatically load variables from `.env`, `.env.default` and `.env.{environment}`, where `environment` is supplied by the flag `--env` in the `fastlane` command.
2. In my `Fastfile`, I need fastlane to load my environment files, that are located *in the parent directory*.
3. I want to keep the behavior of loading of loading the `.env.{environment}` file, when `{environment}` changes according to what I pass in the `--env` flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one worked for me:

1. Using the following `before_all` inside my `platform` block:

```rb
  before_all do |lane|
    Dotenv.overload '../../.env'
    environment = lane_context[SharedValues::ENVIRONMENT]
    unless environment.nil?
        puts "Load .env file of #{environment}"
        Dotenv.overload '../../.env.' + environment
    end
  end
```

2. (Important!) Putting a blank `.env` file in the `fastlane` directory.

The reason to create an empty `.env` is documented in my empty `.env` file:

> ### TL;DR: do NOT delete this empty file
>
> This file is blank to make Fastlane define the `SharedValue::ENVIRONMENT`
> variable, which is part of our `fastlane/Fastfile` configurations.
>
> As you can see in Fastlane's [`cli_tools`](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/1238c394ace2cc06ea8d533e43dd447eb670fd25/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb#L51),
> Fastlane removes the `--env` index from `ARGV` [pretty early](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/1238c394ace2cc06ea8d533e43dd447eb670fd25/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb#L142)
> so we can't know what the user passed to the `--env` parameter.
>
> Unfortunatly, Fastlane search the .env files only in the `fastlane` folder
> and in it's parent folder (the `ios` folder, in our case). It means that,
> in our project, Fastlane won't find any .env files. ([Source](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/e874a47c6e2e0e61590a03d3b71e75e5a505d1ce/fastlane/lib/fastlane/helper/dotenv_helper.rb#L14))
>
> When Fastlane fails to find .env files, it does not call the function
> `load_dot_envs_from`, which is responsible to define the
> `SharedValue::ENVIRONMENT` variable, which we use inside our Fastfile
> ([Source](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/e874a47c6e2e0e61590a03d3b71e75e5a505d1ce/fastlane/lib/fastlane/helper/dotenv_helper.rb#L36))
>
> This file is a hack that will make Fastlane find an empty `.env` file.
> It will then set the `SharedValue::ENVIRONMENT` to the ARGV value.
> We then use `SharedValue::ENVIRONMENT` inside Fastlane to load the right
> file from the right place.